# How to know the string displayed by iOS framework in multiple languages

Tags: ios, iphone, string, frameworks

I'm developing iOS app which is avaialable in multiple languages.

In the app I want to show some strings same as the one displayed with iOS.

For example, when app ask access to Phots iOS shows the strings
"[App name] Would Like to Access Your Photos"

**I'd like to know the following strings in multiple languages.**

- Would like to Access your Photos
- Select Photos...
- Allow Access to All Photos
- Don't Allow

[image]

**Anyone knows how to check the string displayed by iOS framework in multiple languages.**

Or do I need to check them one by one with swithcing language in iOS "Settings"?

Thank you.

Comment: May be this help:- https://medium.com/swift-india/localize-your-apps-to-support-multiple-languages-ios-localization-ac7b612dbc58

Comment: @Saurav_Sharma Thank you for your information. But this explains just how to impliment multiple languages. Now I want to know how to check the strings displayed by iOS without switching languages one by one.